# Passing 2D table from Lua to C++

Tags: c++, lua

I was searching for hours to pass a 2d table from Lua to C++. Lua docs are really sucks.

I have this table on **Lua 5.1** and I want to pass it to c++

```
local costs = {
[0] = {
    1.0,
    1.0,
    1.0,
    1.0,
    1.41,
    1.41,
    1.41,
    1.41,
},
[1] = {
    2.0,
    2.0,
    2.0,
    2.0,
    2.41,
    2.41,
    2.41,
    2.41,
}
```

}

This works with simple, one dimensional table but I can't even get the keys with it

```
int len = lua_rawlen(L, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
  lua_pushinteger(L, i + 1);
  lua_gettable(L, -2);
  printf("Key %i\n", lua_tointeger(L, -1));
  lua_pop(L, 1);
}
```

How can I get this table properly?

Comment: You use `0` as an index. That is not a part of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I found this: [Iterating a multidimensional Lua Table in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920971/iterating-a-multidimensional-lua-table-in-c)

It works. But if there is a better solution I really want to learn. I prefer to use for-loop with size, but `lua_rawlen` always return 1.